# Regex to match comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two types of comment blocks

```
<!-- asdfasd //-->
```

and

```
<!--asdfasd-->

    <!--
<span onclick="window.open('http://www.abc.com?xyz=asfasdfasd')">magic</span>
-->
```

I need to match only second/third and I have this pattern, I have tried so many combinations but, no luck. Also comments contain all the number/alphabets/special characters

```
<!--[\s\S]*?-->
```

Comment: What about this : *<!--// comment -->*. Does this match ?

Comment: `[\s\S]*` matches **any** character which you clearly don't want.

Comment: I think `split()` might do the job too

Answer (score 0):

For the exact Strings as posted above, this works:

```
<!--[^-/]+-->
```

If however, the // may be anywhere in the comment, it won't work.

I'd need some more information for a more accurate solution

cheers
tannerli

Answer (score 0):

Just use a function:

This is the most correct way to do it I believe.

```
var str='<!--asdfasd-->';

var matches= str.match(/<!--.*?(\/*)-->/s)

if (matches&&!matches[1].length>1) alert('You got me :)')
```

Explanation: whether it has the '//' or not we capture it first.

Then we check the lenth of second match, we would match any numberof '/' .

And if there are two slashes or more - it will alert 'false';

http://jsfiddle.net/WNM7G/2/

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<!--[^\/\s]+-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
<!-- *[a-z]+ *-->
```

It should work for `<!--asdfasd-->` and `<!-- asdfasd -->`

**EDIT**

> Also comments contain all the number/alphabets/special characters???

Well add all expected special characters without forget escaping:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9"!\?_-]+
```

Comment: Nomik, not working with following if comments has line breaks ...

<!-- 
asdfasd 
-->

Comment: still has some issues, not working if comments has html tags

<!--
<span onclick="window.open('http://www.abc.com?xyz=asfasdfasd')">magic</span>
-->

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--(\\?|.|\s).*[^/^/]-->
```

this is working for me

Answer (score 0):

try following pattern:

```
<!--[\s\S]+?-->
```

its working for me.